Cannot find module './DataTable.vue' or its corresponding type declarations
Im using Nuxt 3, mostly default settings.
My folder structure for a component:
...
├── components
│   ├── MainNav.vue
│   ├── PageHeader.vue
│   ├── data-table
│   │   ├── DataTable.vue
│   │   └── index.ts

My index.ts:
export { default as DataTable } from "./DataTable.vue";

I keep getting this vue-tsc error (below)... What am I doing that's dumb? After hours of searching I can only find very outdated Nuxt 2 answers.
I have tried a bunch of attempts at adding paths to my to no avail...
My nuxt.config.ts
  typescript: {
    strict: true,
    typeCheck: true,
  },

 ERROR                                                                                                                                                                            5:26:26 AM
 ERROR(vue-tsc)  Cannot find module './DataTable.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.
 FILE  .../components/data-table/index.ts:1:38

  > 1 | export { default as DataTable } from "./DataTable.vue";
      |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    2 |


AHhHHHH! The answer maybe this... https://nuxt.com/docs/api/nuxt-config#shim

Did your problem fix?
